# Disable jsession id from filter in spring

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have written a filter that extends `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`.

The following is the overridden method:

```
 @Override
   public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
        throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {


    if (StringUtils.isNoneBlank(cookie)) {
            return authenticationProvider.authenticate(token);
            //Here I want to return jsession id and establish a session.

    } else {
       return handleInSomeOtherWay(httpServletRequest);
         //Here I DONT want to return jsessionid
    }

}
```

How can I achieve returning jsession id in one path and not in another path? I tried to set `allowSessionCreation = false`, but that did not help.

Comment: You cannot garantuee that. There is no way you can now in this place if there is nothing down stream creating a session. So in short you cannot.

Comment: Thanks Deinum. What is the way out then ? How can I solve this problem

Comment: As stated you cannot, as there is no way you can garantuee that nothing downstream needs a session.